# Should it be "SO" or "BECAUSE" for this sentence to be logical: "They removed a section of genetic code so it no longer worked"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, conjunctions

This is from the BBC, [Alyssa's revolutionary cancer treatment](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-63859184)

**In Alyssa's therapy, each of the base edits involved breaking a section of genetic code so it no longer worked.**

I did not quite understand the logic in this sentence. I understand that they broke a section of the genetic code because it was no longer working. In other words, it had already stopped working, so, they decided to remove that section.

But if you read **".....so it no longer worked."**,** it means that "they removed that section in order for it not to work any more.", which would not make sense.

So, I think it should be "**....because it no longer worked"**, NOT **"....so it no longer worked"**.

Do you think so?

Answer (score 3):

Logically both make sense but have different meanings.  The writer has chosen "so" and that (we should assume) is the intended meaning.  The base edits broke a section of (working) genetic code, with the result that the section stopped working.

<sub>To understand why this makes sense *scientifically* remember that cancer involves cells growing uncontrollably.  The cells in a tumour are growing *too* well, and so breaking their code causes the cells to stop growing. You have to break DNA to break the cancer cells to stop them from growing.</sub>

Comment: I took my drunk mother's car keys away **so** [that] she could not drive her car.

Comment: She could not drive the car because you took the keys. [Cause & effect, because & so]

Comment: @Tetsujin I took away the keys to cause her to be unable to drive.